# My Dapp work on the private testnet but not in the public one

Tags: testnets, ropsten

I have created this simple Dapp and it work fine in the private testnet & java VM inside Remix and outside it using a web interface. The problem come when it will be used in the "public" testnet (Ropsten). It send the transaction and execute the function but never send the ether from the contract to the address. I' ve already set the value of the contract to the correct value.

Sorry for bad English

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract DApp
{
    uint256 acconto;
    uint256 saldo;
    address committent;
    address technician;
    bool done = false;
    uint timeFinish;

modifier onlyCom
{
    if (msg.sender != committent)
    {
        assert(true);
    }
    else
    {
        _;
    }
}

function DApp (uint256 _acconto, uint256 _saldo, address _technician, uint _Time) payable public
{
    if (msg.value >= _acconto + _saldo) {
    acconto = _acconto * 1000000000000000000;
    saldo = _saldo * 1000000000000000000;
    committent = msg.sender;
    technician = _technician;
    timeFinish = block.timestamp + _Time;

    technician.transfer(acconto);
    } else revert();
}

function Done () public onlyCom
{
    done = true;
}

function reciveReward () payable public
{
    if(done == true)
    {
        technician.transfer(saldo);
        selfdestruct(this);
    }
    else
    {
        if(block.timestamp >= timeFinish)
        {
            committent.transfer(saldo);
            selfdestruct(this);
        }

        assert(true);
    }
}
}
```

Edit:
This is how it should work:
[image]
I write the data for the transaction

[image]
In the photo I putted the value of contract with an error, I will correct it in the last photo.
Basically now the deployer is paying 4 ether + transaction cost.
The "acconto" goes directly to the technician address.
The rest remains into the contract.

[image]
This is the change of money (In the first try only the first part of the contract worked fine because the value wasn' t enough)

[image]
I remaded the whole transaction at the receiveReward call the remaining part goes to technician and all worked as I wanted.

Why in the Ropsten Test Net it doesn' t work? It doesn' t send ether or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: sembra scritto male di proposito

Comment: @siid scusa se non posseggo il tuo livello di inglese, :(

Comment: Non mi riferivo all'inglese

Comment: @siid a cosa allora?

Comment: al codice solidity

Comment: hai risolto poi?

Comment: @siid è il primo che scrivo (e probabilmente anche l' ultimo) per un mio amico... Scusa se ti ho aggredito così :) No, non ho ancora risolto, i fondi sembrano non arrivare all' altro utente, ma vengono scalati correttamente.

Comment: acconto e saldo sono wei o ether?

Comment: Metto il contract.value a ether e moltiplico l' acconto per 18 zeri per portarlo a ether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, should be logically identical. I found a couple of syntax errors:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract DApp {
    uint256 acconto;
    uint256 saldo;
    address committent;
    address technician;
    bool started;
    uint256 timeFinish;

    modifier onlyCom() { require(msg.sender == committent); _; }
    modifier onlyAfter(uint _time) { require(now > _time); _; }

    constructor (uint256 _acconto, uint256 _saldo, address _technician) public {
        technician = _technician;
        committent = msg.sender;
        acconto = _acconto;
        saldo = _saldo;
        started = false;
    }

    function start(uint256 _time) public onlyCom() payable {
        require(started == false);
        require(msg.value >= acconto + saldo);
        started = true;
        timeFinish = now + _time;
        technician.transfer(acconto);
    }

    function good() public onlyCom() { selfdestruct(technician); }
    function bad() public onlyCom() onlyAfter(timeFinish) { selfdestruct(committent); }
}
```

Comment: The acconto & saldo is now in ether or wei, because it doesn' t multiply for nothing. L' acconto e il saldo ora sono in ether o wei, perché non è moltiplicato per nulla come nel mio programma... Lo devo poi moltiplicare nell' interfaccia con web3?

Comment: secondo me conviene, si

Comment: Funziona, grazie mille

Answer (score 2):

Some issues that appears when switching from a private testnet to a public network:

- Not enough gas. Some IDEs and wallet can estimate the correct value of gas required by a transaction, but when your program creates the transaction it will use a default value that can be not enough (it used to be 100k).
- Gas price too low. In a private testnet often the price is fixed and all transactions will be processed. In a public testnet the gas price will fluctuate with the demand. Low gas price might cause a transaction to take longer to be mined.
- Not waiting for confirmation of the transaction. In a private testnet transactions are confirmed quickly, but in a public network your transaction have to compete with others pending transactions for space in blocks. It might take several blocks before your transaction is confirmed, and until them your contract will not reflect the changes made in the transaction.

Comment: I checked all of this multiple time but it continue to don' t work. What can I do? Sorry for bad English

Comment: Do you have the transaction id when it failed? It seems your parameters `_acconto`, `_saldo` are in ethers and you compare them against `msg.value` that is in wei. So it is possible you are sending to the contract less ethers than it required.

Comment: I think this is the transaction id, but I' m not sure.. Contract creation: 0xbc63d42af64ce272a0b7517ba2daa50c579af5f7d2bae66de00672474f12fba2
Function Done: 0x66d260e9a37346998aee63657ad5fca7b5d3ccec71f8130ec7504316dc89c542
ReceiveReward: 0xc12456396112c9e241700c99927a442655e69b4671aac89db4866bb6fc148838
This is the testnet test, the one in the photo is on Virtual Machine. Testnet Ropsten. Sorry for bad English

Comment: The problem with that transactions is when you [create the contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xbc63d42af64ce272a0b7517ba2daa50c579af5f7d2bae66de00672474f12fba2) you set `_acconto` and `_saldo` to zero. When you call [`ReceiveReward()`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb98ab8944f9d2eeac61fbf5d0a67cc3aed182e24c365f6b67226fc9ce43e9117) it transfer `saldo` to technician address (but it is zero!) and then it [selfdestructs](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb98ab8944f9d2eeac61fbf5d0a67cc3aed182e24c365f6b67226fc9ce43e9117#internal) and it will ignore further calls.

Comment: Why it set it to zero? I multiply the wei value for 10^18... I don' t understand why it set it to 0. But hopefully I know that it isn' t a later problem but a constructor problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: The constructor parameters both are set to zero.